# Change default document in appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a `ASP.NET` core application with an `appsettings.json` file. I didn't create the application, it's just running on my server. When I go to the server, I'm sent to `default.html`, but instead, I'd like to be sent to `default2.html`. Is there a parameter for `appsettings.json` that I can use to select a different default document?

Comment: Its unusual for an ASP.Net core application to be serving up static pages, especially as a default document. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43090718/setting-index-html-as-default-page-in-asp-net-core) for details on how it is achieved. Do you have access to the source code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the source code. I believe the static pages are basically just wrappers with iframes or something in them. default.html shows a menu bar, default2.html doesn't. But what you're saying is basically, that it's not possible to change the default document through appsettings.json?

Comment: Do you have access to `launchSettings.json`? And can you view the source code on e.g GitHub or wherever it is even though you cannot change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set the default document using the `appsettings.json` file.